# How to call a singleton method from a Java POJO?

Tags: java, methods, interface, singleton, instance

I wondered if it would be possible to call from a POJO a singleton bean's method  through its interface. Maybe this idea is wrong or the architecture...but this is what I would like to accomplish if it is possible, because this is the architecture of the project. 
I notice that when I call getInstance() (the method from the singleton's interface) from the POJO, there is an error occuring, telling me that the method has to be static, but if I make the method static, then I have to write the implementation in the interface and I can't get the singleton instance.

Comment: Remove the interface and make the method static. You can't call an instance method before you have an actual instance to call it on, and you don't want to call it on an instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current approach with the interface is flawed. By default, all methods in an interface (up until Java 8) are static, and are implemented by instance methods in the implementing class.

This means, this is not an option. After all, you'll need to run the method to create an instance, meaning, you don't have an instance yet, so you have no instance to call it on.

Putting the same static method in an abstract class you extend, is also not a solution: a super class should never be aware of it's subclasses. If it is a static method (which it needs to be), you need to keep it in the class itself: a static method in an abstract class can (through an anonymous implementation of the abstract class) return an instance of the abstract class, but this is not the same as an instance of the subclass, which is what you are looking for.

In order to use this method for the subclass, you will need to inherit it from the super class. But, it will still return an instance of the super class. You'll need to overwrite the method in the subclass by the correct one, so the best solution is to add it straight in your Singleton class.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to have static methods in your interfaces (at least not until Java 8). Something like this is not allowed:

```
MyInterface var = new MyImplementingClass();
var.staticMethod();
```

Just remove the interface and do your static method call against the class where the static method resides.

Search a bit for the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) - the 'standard' way to do this involves classes and not interfaces, so rethink your design.

Comment: `the 'standard' way to do this involves classes` or enums

Answer (score -1):

The idea seems to be wrong. A static method is always at a class level and hence you can never declare a method as static in a Java interface(you can do this in Java 8). However, this seems like the wrong design. If you really want to do something like this -

```
1)Make the Interface an abstract class.
2)Create a static method called getInstance();
3)Extend the abstract class in your POJO singleton class.
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: since he would have to overwrite (you can't override static members) the method in order to return an instance of the class itself, what is the point of this?
Having an abstract class in this situation is pointless. All he needs is one static method in the class itself.

Comment: The abstract class is not just for having the static method. Currently he has an interface that would be containing multiple method signatures that the class implementing that interface should override. He can still have all of those in this abstract class and use the static method. P.S - This answer is just because he wants to do it this way, ideally he should have the static method in the singleton class itself

Comment: Not ideally, it has to be there, point. the superclass is not aware of the subclasses' existence, hence the abstract class would return an instance of .... what, actually? it can't return one from itself, unless an anonymous one, and it can't logically return an instance of the class he needs.Anyway you turn it, he still needs that static method in his singleton class.

Comment: Thank you Stultuske for your explanations, but I can't mark your answer as correct and helpful, because you wrote in comments. How should I do it?

Comment: @uzzi I can add them in an answer, if you like.